# NSAlert keyboard event propagation

Tags: macos-high-sierra, swift4.1, nsalert

I wrote an app using Xcode 9.4 and Swift 4.1 for Mac OS X High Sierra. It has a custom NSView and a custom NSViewController. The custom NSView class has override functions defined for handling keyboard events (keyUp and keyDown). (It also has an override for acceptsFirstResponder property that returns true.)

If the user types X key, the app builds an NSAlert object with message text and 2 buttons and displays it in sheet modal form. The alert can be dismissed in one of 3 ways:

1. mouse clicked on one of the NSAlert buttons
2. using SPACE bar from keyboard
3. using RETURN key from keyboard

The problem is that in cases 2 and 3 the keyboard event for the key used to dismiss the NSAlert is propagated to the custom NSView keyboard handlers. Is there a way to disable this propagation?

Comment: Do you get the keyDown or is the alert dismissed by the keyDown and is the keyUp not handled?

Comment: it appears to not get the keyDown, just the keyUp (i.e. it appears that the NSAlert handles the keyDown and does not propagate it, but does propagate the keyUp). So maybe the alert is dismissed at the keyDown event? In that case I guess I could set a flag in my keyDown and then ignore the keyUp event if the flag is not set?

Comment: So, based on  Willeke's question, it appears that the NSAlert is dismissed at keyDown event and so the keyUp is sent to the NSView class. A solution that appears to work is to set a flag in the NSView class keyDown override and then  process the keyUp event only if that flag is set (and, of course, reset it in that case as well).